# What will happen if I have two msi's creating same folder?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wise

If the folder structure X/Y/A is created by 32 bit msi first and X/Y/B is created by the 64 bit msi. What will happen to the X and Y ? Which msi id they will have?

Comment: What do you mean by "which msi id"? Folders don't have any ids.

Comment: I meant which msi will uninstall X and Y folder?

Comment: The last one. Folder is only removed if it's empty

Comment: I have on problem while uninstalling. When the order of installation was 32 bit followed by 64 bit X/Y was getting removed but now I have changed the order of installation 64 -bit followed by 32 bit now X/Y is not getting removed although content inside X/Y is empty. And in both the case order of un-installation is 64 bit first and then the 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

The uninstall order is the one which matters. The empty folders will be correctly removed if you uninstall them backwards compared to how they installed, [i.e. LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

When you install the second MSI, it will find the X and Y folders on the machine. So if it gets uninstalled as the last one it will leave those folders on the machine even if they are empty, because its installation did not created them. (the installation of the first MSI created. But when you uninstall the first MSI before the second one it will leave the folders there because they are not empty, i.e. containing files installed by the second MSI)

You could try using [RemoveFolders action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).